# Running scrapy spider but blank output. python

Tags: python, web-scraping, logging, scrapy, pyspider

I am trying to have this spider go through a list of 1600 urls contained in a csv and pull emails and phone numbers from the page. If anyone already has such a program I'd be happy to use it, but also i would love to know where I went wrong. Here is my code, I have passed it through chat gpt to tighten it up and annotate it.

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd
import os
import re
import logging


class Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'business_scrape'

    def extract_emails(self, text):
        # Extract email addresses using a comprehensive regex pattern
        emails = re.findall(
            r'[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}', text)
        return emails

    def extract_phone(self, text):
        # Extract phone numbers
        phone_numbers = re.findall(
            r'(?:(?:\+\d{1,2}\s?)?\(?\d{3}\)?[-.\s]?)?\d{3,4}[-.\s]?\d{4}', text)
        return phone_numbers

    def start_requests(self):
        # Read the initial CSV file with columns [name, url, category]
        csv = 'bozeman_businesses.csv'  # Specify your CSV file
        init_df = pd.read_csv(csv)

        for _, row in init_df.iterrows():
            name = row['name']
            url = row['url']
            category = row['category']

            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_link, meta={'name': name, 'category': category})

    def parse_link(self, response):
        name = response.meta['name']
        category = response.meta['category']

        # Initialize logging
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename='scrapy.log', format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

        # Log the start of crawling
        logging.info('Crawling started.')
        for word in self.reject:
            if word in str(response.url):
                return

        html_text = str(response.text)
        try:
            # Extract email addresses using the function
            mail_list = self.extract_emails(html_text)

            # Extract phone numbers using the function
            phone_numbers = self.extract_phone(html_text)

            # Ensure 'email' and 'phone' lists have the same length
            min_length = min(len(mail_list), len(phone_numbers))
            mail_list = mail_list[:min_length]
            phone_numbers = phone_numbers[:min_length]

            dic = {'name': [name], 'category': [category], 'email': mail_list,
                   'phone': phone_numbers, 'url': [str(response.url)]}

        except Exception as e:
            # Handle the failure by setting "NA" values
            self.logger.error(f'Error scraping {response.url}: {e}')
            dic = {'name': [name], 'category': [category], 'email': ['NA'],
                   'phone': ['NA'], 'url': [str(response.url)]}

        # Check if the output file exists and prompt the user if it does
        if os.path.exists(self.path):
            response = self.ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
            if response is False:
                return

        # Create or overwrite the output file
        self.create_or_overwrite_file(self.path)

        # Append the data to the output CSV file
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic)
        df.to_csv(self.path, mode='a', header=False, index=False)

    # Define the reject list and output file path
    reject = ['example.com', 'example2.com']  # Adjust as needed
    path = 'output.csv'  # Adjust the output file path as needed

    def ask_user(self, question):
        response = input(question + ' y/n' + '\n')
        return response.lower() == 'y'

    def create_or_overwrite_file(self, path):
        response = False
        if os.path.exists(path):
            response = self.ask_user('File already exists, replace?')
            if response is False:
                return

        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.close()
```

My log is pretty long so here are some excerpts:

```
2023-09-21 15:51:02 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.hrblock.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-09-21 15:51:02 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 http://www.gallatinvalleytaxservices.com>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-09-21 15:51:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (308) to <GET https://www.amaticscpa.com/> from <GET http://www.amaticscpa.com>
2023-09-21 15:51:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.hrblock.com/> from <GET http://www.hrblock.com>
2023-09-21 15:51:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://amaticscpa.com/> from <GET https://www.amaticscpa.com/>
2023-09-21 15:51:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.hrblock.com/> (referer: None)
2023-09-21 15:51:03 [root] INFO: Crawling started.
```

Seems good so far

```
file "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 502, in dict_to_mgr
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, dtype=dtype, typ=typ, consolidate=copy)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 120, in arrays_to_mgr
    index = _extract_index(arrays)
  File "/Users/me/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 674, in _extract_index
    raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length"
```

I feel like this error about array lengths is the problem. I tried adding NA values if the process failed. Didn't seem to work :(

This error also popped up.

```
2023-09-21 15:52:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.hpwcpas.com/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
2023-09-21 15:52:03 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://www.hpwcpas.com/robots.txt>: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionLost: Connection to the other side was lost in a non-clean fashion: Connection lost.>]
```

The rest of the log is essentially repeated.

What I did and expected:

- I tried adding try, except loops to skip problem sites and put NA values in.
- I expected that even if I could not scrape the info i wanted I would still have a csv with the business name, url, and NA values
- I'd also be interested in how I can better debug this myself

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have made a few adjustments with loads of success:

1. The output file was being overwritten at each URL
2. Invalid URLs caused the spider to quite
3. Scrapped information was put into a list then added to a dictionary, different list lengths caused errors.

Solution 1: Move self.create into start_requests function rather than parse_link; Add dataframe header if os.path.getsize(path) == 0; And remove ask_user function from parse_link.

Solution 2: add this to the start_requests function. CSV of urls contains 'Not found' Strings.

```
 # Check if the URL is "Not found" and skip it
        if url.strip() == 'Not found':
            self.logger.warning(f'Skipping invalid URL for {name}')
            continue
```

Solution 3: I made sure to convert the list to a comma delineated string.

Still having problems with the general scraping method. I want the emails from websites, but a more rhobust system would be needed to navigate through pages and metadata to grab them.

If your are copying me, make sure to exclude image files often in the form image@2x.png/jpg from the email search.